# What is the 'Find in Project' / 'Search in Project' keyboard shortcut in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've found the [VScode keyboard shortcuts for Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) and [Mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf) but  the 'Search in Project' isn't listed.

**How do I get to 'Search in Project' using the keyboard?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pressing Ctrl+shift+f that should do it

Comment: How to I limit this just to my files/directory? It's searching a lot of external headers **EDIT:** Found it in `Settings > Features > Search > Exclusions` (I added `**/vcpkg_installed`)